# CUPS, suggest driver for Windows

Tags: cups

I have configured CUPS PDF on the Linux side and printing works fine from Windows via IPP (over HTTP).

However when I add the printer to Windows, I need to manually select the driver to be used. **Is is possible to configure CUPS to tell Windows which *already installed driver* it should use?**

There are examples available on how to setup Samba to provide the drivers, but I would would not like to use smb. Also I'm not looking to automatically download the driver to Windows - I would just like to skip the manual printer selection phase.

Comment: Any progress on this already?

Answer (score 0):

If your only purpose is to print to the 'PDF' queue on CUPS, you may install any (generic) PostScript driver on Windows. (The only options you're interested in is to select page sizes, color or grayscale print, and resolution of images.)

Windows will send PostScript to CUPS, and CUPS will transform it to PDF.